# Why doesn't grep -n "[^aeiou]+" return lines that don't contain vowels when they exist?

Tags: regex, grep

I am running bash shell on Android using termux

Aim is to print chars or words which don't contain any vowels in them.

Seq of cmds typed:

```
$ cat f4
a
b
c
bb
$ grep -n "[^aeiou]+" f4
$
```

Unable to understand why the regular expression is not giving the expected output.

Comment: aside: `cmd` is the Windows shell. It doesn't apply here.

Comment: Also, your question title should be specific enough that someone can identify your particular question with it. Not just "I'm having trouble with X", but "I'm having *this specific* problem with X". The purpose of this site is to build a database of questions and answers that can be useful to people, and part of being useful is having a title that lets someone identify if they have the same problem from a summary in search results.

Comment: (also, commands are case-sensitive on Linux, so you can't run `Cat` instead of `cat` there and have it work; I've taken the liberty of editing accordingly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually in `GNU grep` you don't need to enable the `-E` for extended regular expression support, just escape the `+` to deprive of its special meaning

```
grep -n "[^aeiou]\+" file
2:b
3:c
4:bb
```

Quoting from the page [Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html),

> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ‘?’, ‘+’, ‘{’, ‘|’, ‘(’, and ‘)’ lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions ‘\?’, ‘\+’, ‘\{’, ‘\|’, ‘\(’, and ‘\)’.
>
> Traditional egrep did not support the ‘{’ meta-character, and some egrep implementations support ‘{’ instead, so portable scripts should avoid ‘{’ in ‘grep -E’ patterns and should use ‘[{]’ to match a literal ‘{’.

---

Also you can simply enable the `-E, --extended-regexp` flag in `GNU grep` for that

```
grep -En "[^aeiou]+" file
2:b
3:c
4:bb
```

Refer the [Bracket Expressions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-grep-regular-expressions-to-search-for-text-patterns-in-linux#extended-regex) from the embedded link.

Comment: @yolob21: Thanks in `SO` is accepting the answer :)

Comment: BTW, this doesn't actually return "lines that don't have any vowels in them" -- it would need to be anchored to both start and end for that.

Comment: grep -n "[^aeiou]\+" file , this option isn't working , behaves the same way without -E option

Comment: @yolob21, ...so, I'm suggesting that your test cases aren't very good. If you had something that started with a consonant but contained a vowel later in your test data, that would have come out. `foo`, for instance -- the current `grep` will return it, because while you're returning lines with 1-or-more consonants, you aren't restricting that to be lines that consist **only** of 1-or-more consonants.

Comment: @yolob21, using backslash escapes to get ERE extensions in BRE, such as `\+`, is a GNUism -- if you're on a platform with a non-GNU grep, it isn't expected to work, and you'll need `-E`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: updated answer to let know the `GNUism`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy                            $ grep -En "^[^aeiou]+$" file- I suppose this will handle such cases iff words are given on separate lines

Answer (score 1):

First: `+` is an ERE extension. To build an equivalent BRE command might look like:

```
grep '[^aeiou]\{1,\}$'
```

...or you can add the `-E` argument or use `egrep` to enable such extensions.

---

Second: If your aim is to find words with **no** vowels, rather than simply words that contain at least one non-vowel character, you need to anchor your regex:

```
grep '^[^aeiou]\{1,\}$'
```

or, as an ERE,

```
grep -E '^[^aeiou]+$'
```

The `^` on the front and the `$` on the back are anchors: They ensure that what you're matching goes all the way from the start of the line to the end of it, rather than that that exists *somewhere* in the line.

Comment: Or, more simply, use `-v` to match the complement: `grep -v '[aeiou]'`.